# How to set a NULL value into a number in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table `tablea` as show below.

I want to insert a row into the `tablea` by taking the previous value from the previous insertion i.e. let it be the `MAX(pid)`, so by default I have nothing in my database so the query of max returns null so, then i need to set the pid into 0 when I got a null while inserting for the first time.

This is my [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/290e5/1)
I tried by using few SQL statements as I commented in the FIDDLE.

```
create table tablea(
  sno serial,
  pid integer,
  pname text
  );

-- I am unable to retrieve the null value from the database and store it with pid as 0 so i had inserted this default value

insert into tablea(sno,pid,pname)
values(0,0,'default');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_details(_pname text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    _pid int;
begin
_pid := ((select MAX(pid) from tablea)+1);
 insert into tablea(pid,pname)
values(_pid,_pname);
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Are you aware that this `max(pid)` solution will give you incorrect results in case of concurrent transactions?

Comment: then in that case what should i consider to avoid errors at the stage of concurrent executions @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should i use any locks to prevent the conflict when i run it on concurrent transactions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shall i raise another question on this topic :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while it's not what I'd do in my db, here's working example of your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_details(_pname text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    _pid int;
begin
   _pid := (select max(pid) from tablea);
   _pid := coalesce(_pid, 0) + 1;

   insert into tablea(pid,pname)
   values(_pid,_pname);
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2d5dd/1)

you can do it without variable at all:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_details(_pname text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
   insert into tablea(pid,pname)
   values (coalesce((select max(pid) from tablea), 0) + 1, _pname);
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```